# How to dynamicaly change a ng-included view?

Tags: angularjs, templates

I've the simplified following architecture:

```
<section ng-controller="myController">
    <!-- Content -->
    <button>Clic here !</button>
</section>
<aside ng-include="nav.html">
    <!-- Content -->
</aside>
```

How can I dynamicaly change the view included into the `aside` tag when I clic on the `button`, driven by the `myController` controller?

Note that my controller's scope doesn't include the `aside` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Set the ng-include to a variable on your scope.

```
<aside ng-include="currentTemplate">
    <!-- Content -->
</aside>
```

add an ng-click to the button that calls a function to change this variable

```
    <button ng-click="setTemplate()">Click here !</button>
```

Add the function and the variable to your controller:

```
$scope.currentTemplate = 'firstTemplate.html';

$scope.setTemplate = function(){
    $scope.currentTemplate = 'clickedTemplate.html';
}
```

That should do it.

Fiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/AU6Mr/1/